# Get the name of the variable which has the second lowest/smallest value with PHP

Tags: php

I have 4 variables and each of those have an integer assigned to them. Could anybody please let me know how I can get the name of the variable which has the second smallest value?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you your attempt you have tried so far? We really need to see a try at this before we can help!

Comment: Put them into an array, sort the array, pull the second index.

Comment: i have searched and tried to put them in array and sort the value. it returns the index number not the name of the variable.

Comment: Add what you tried, we can tell you where you went wrong. Otherwise we're just guessing or throwing code at you.

Comment: $var1=3;  $var2=4; $var3=7;      $arr=array($var1, $var2, $var3);     arrsort($arr); $keys = array_keys($arr); echo $keys[4];

Comment: @ysalemo If you have four variables why does your code only include three?

Comment: `array_keys` returns the corresponding key, not value. Also `arrsort` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use compact to set the variables to one array, sort the array, then use array slice to get the second value.
Then optionally echo the key of the second value.

```
$a = 2;
$b = 7;
$c = 6;
$d = 1;

$arr = compact('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

asort($arr);
$second = array_slice($arr,1,1);
Echo "variable name " . Key($second) ."\n";

Echo "value " . ${key($second)};
```

https://3v4l.org/SVdCq

Updated the code with how to access the original variable from the array

Comment: i tried the above but the echo is not returning anything.

Comment: What code have you used? The code clearly works, so you must have done something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a structured way of naming your variables eg `prefix_x` there is no real way.

Recommended way is using an array like this:

```
$array = array(
  "a" => 3,
  "b" => 2,
  "c" => 1,
  "d" => 6
);


// Sort the array descending but keep the keys.
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php.
asort($array);

// Fetch the keys and get the second item (index 1).
// This is the key you are looking for per your question.
$second_key = array_keys($array)[1];

// Dumping the result to show it's the second lowest value.
var_dump($array[$second_key]); // int(2).
```

To be more in line with your question you can create your array like this.

```
$array = array();
$array['variable_one'] = $variable_one;
$array['some_random_var'] = $some_random_var;
$array['foo'] = $foo;
$array['bar']= $bar;

// Same code as above here.
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have all Variables in an Array. You can do this this way:

```
$array = array(
 'a' => 3,
 'b' => 6,
 'c' => 2,
 'd' => 1
);
```

or this way:

```
$array['a'] = 3;
$array['b'] = 6;
// etc
```

Then you need to sort the Items with natsort() to receive a natural Sorting.

```
natsort($array);
```

Then you flip the Array-Keys with the Values (In Case you want the Value, skip this Line)

```
$array = array_flip($array);
```

After this you jump to the next Item in the Array (Position 1) by using next();

```
echo next($array);
```

Makes in Total a pretty short Script:

```
$array = array(
 'a' => 3,
 'b' => 6,
 'c' => 2,
 'd' => 1
);

natsort($array);
$array = array_flip($array);
echo next($array);
```

Comment: this is returning the value in the variable not the name of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 4 variables for 4 integer values, you can use an array to store these values. Sort the array and print the second index of the array i.e. 1.

```
<?php

    $x = array(2,3,1,6);

    $i = 0, $j = 0, $temp = 0;

    for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){

        for($j=0; $j < 4 - $i; j++){

            if($x[$j] > $x[$j+1]){

                $temp = $x[$j];

                $x[$j] = $x[$j+1];

                $x[$j+1] = $temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++){
        echo $x[$j];
    }

    echo $x[1];

?>
```

Comment: Seems like a very ineffective way of doing it. 3 for loops, multiple arrays and variables :). Think your solution is the most memory intensive one, but it might work though.